# Selenium Chrome Driver Error: TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Tags: python, linux, selenium, google-chrome

I'm testing a financial application through the use of selenium, and I have already fixed the driver specification to what my browser uses in my operating system. But now there is a NoneType Error with the send_keys(os.environget([Variable]). Here is my code.....

```
# plotting Trends
import re, os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import numpy as np
from numpy import inf
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
import time
import seaborn as sns
sns.set() # setting seaborn default for plots
from pdb import set_trace


load_dotenv()

dr = webdriver.Chrome("/home/name/Desktop/chromedriver") #chrome_options=chrome_options)
dr.get("https://www.screener.in/login/")

username = dr.find_element_by_id("id_username")
username.clear()
SCRUSER = "email@user.com"
username.send_keys(os.environ.get(SCRUSER))

password = dr.find_element_by_id("id_password")
password.clear()
SCRPASSWORD = "password"
password.send_keys(os.environ.get(SCRPASSWORD))
```

.....

Here is my error:

```
  /home/robert/Desktop/diagram1.py:22: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  dr = webdriver.Chrome("/home/robert/Desktop/chromedriver") #chrome_options=chrome_options)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/robert/Desktop/diagram1.py", line 28, in <module>
    username.send_keys(os.environ.get(SCRUSER))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 511, in send_keys
    {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/utils.py", line 153, in keys_to_typing
    for i in range(len(val)):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: Value is shown to be in the keys_to_typing function in the utils.py file on lines 142-155.

Comment: I think the output of `os.environ.get(SCRUSER)` could be `None` instead of a string. Could you try printing out the value using `print(os.environ.get(SCRUSER))`?

Comment: Yes, they are both none types, so how do I change that?

Comment: Do you have the value stored in  environment variable `SCRUSER` and `SCRPASSWORD`? You can confirm it by printing out the value using `print(os.environ.get('SCRUSER'))` and `print(os.environ.get('SCRPASSWORD'))`

Comment: Try `username.send_keys(SCRUSER)`

Comment: No it's still not stored in the environment variable even though I assigned it, by os.environ.get("texts")

Comment: I tried the answer suggestion by: SCRUSER= os.environ.get("text") then sending the keys by username.send_keys(SCRUSER).

Comment: Oh I see, so where is the actual user name and password value stored? Is it stored in linux environment variables or and .env file? What is the environment variable names that store them?

Comment: I'm using kali linux so my environment profile is under the /etc directory, would this be the right file?                                                                     PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
COMMAND_NOT_FOUND_INSTALL_PROMPT=1
POWERSHELL_UPDATECHECK=Off
POWERSHELL_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1
SCRUSER="email@user.com"
SCRPASSWORD="password"

Answer (score 0):

```
SCRUSER = "email@user.com"
username.send_keys(os.environ.get(SCRUSER))
```

It appears that you are assigning the username and password a value, but then trying to call its environment variable.
Instead of looking at your .env file for the value of "SCRUSER", it is looking for the value of "email@user.com"

Try:

```
SCRUSER = os.environ.get("SCRUSER")
SCRPASSWORD = os.environ.get("SCRPASSWORD")
```

Then, when you send the keys, just send the variable itself

Or, you can just add quotes and not assign it to a variable.

```
username.send_keys(os.environ.get("SCRUSER"))
password.send_keys(os.environ.get("SCRPASSWORD"))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but I'm still getting the same error when I tried the last example. When I tried the first example it didn't throw an error, but didn't pass the keys.

Comment: To be clear, in the .env file you should have a variable:
SCRUSER = "username"

Then as long as you call os.environ.get("SCRUSER") - (with quotes around it)it should work.

Try printing out the SCRUSER variable after calling it to make sure its getting assigned properly

Comment: From my load_dotenv i didn't seem to have an environment file, how would I access it on my kali linux machine?

Comment: I fixed it by importing "selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys" and added Keys.ENTER after send keys, took me a while but I got it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the environment variables `SCRUSER` and `SCRPASSWORD` hasn't been loaded in your script. One of the possible approach is to store your environment in an env file in the following format

creds.env

```
SCRUSER="email@user.com"
SCRPASSWORD="password"
```

and then in the python code, you can load it using the command `load_dotenv(<path to env file>)`

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv("creds.env")
print(os.environ.get("SCRUSER"))
print(os.environ.get("SCRPASSWORD"))
```

After the env file is loaded, you can access to the value using

```
scuser = os.environ.get("SCRUSER")
scpassword = os.environ.get("SCRPASSWORD")
```